# Bulk trimming all columns in a table

Tags: plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to create a small PL\SQL code to remove all leading and ending spaces in a table. I created 2 files, column_trimmer & stop. The stop.sql is nothing more than a message to say have a nice day. The column_trimmer has the main code. All I need is to grab the specified table and then grab all the columns in that table and remove leading and ending spaces. This is what I have so far..

```
ACCEPT column_name CHAR PROMPT 'Please specify the table name'
```

> ```
>      NEED CODE IN HERE TO GRAB TABLE NAME, THEN ALL COLUMNS IN IT
>               AND APPLY IT TO THE CODE BELOW
> ```

```
UPDATE EWS_PHONE_SLX SET columnname = TRIM(columnname);
ACCEPT response CHAR PROMPT 'Task completed! Would you like to trim all columns in another table? '
SET TERM OFF

SELECT CASE LOWER('&&response.') WHEN 'yes' THEN 'column_trimmer' ELSE 'no' END AS script
FROM DUAL;

SET TERM ON

@&script
```

Comment: ignore ews_phone_slx

Comment: After fixing the data in the tables, can you do the trim at the point of data entry rather than after the fact, or as a trigger perhaps to stop the problem from happening in the future?

Comment: Don't forget error handling around the update statement.

Answer (score 1):

Here ist a little plsql procedure (not tested):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE trim_all_columns(p_table IN VARCHAR)
AS
  v_sql   VARCHAR2(32767);
  v_first BOOLEAN := true;
BEGIN
  v_sql := 'UPDATE ' || p_table || ' SET ';
  FOR c1 IN (
    SELECT column_name
      FROM user_tab_columns
     WHERE table_name = p_table
       AND data_type = 'VARCHAR2'
  ) LOOP
    IF v_first = false THEN
      v_sql := v_sql || ', ';
    END IF;
    v_sql := v_sql || c1.column_name || ' = TRIM(' || c1.column_name || ')';    
    v_first := false;
  END LOOP;
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql;
END;
/
```

and here an example call for a table named "MY_TABLE":

```
BEGIN
  trim_all_columns('MY_TABLE');
END;
/
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Well I was kinda hoping it was just a few lines to add into the code I provided

Comment: If you want it in just one line, you can: `BEGIN trim_all_columns('MY_TABLE'); END;`

Comment: CLEAR SCREEN
SET VERIFY OFF
ACCEPT table_name CHAR PROMPT 'Please specify the table name' 
CLEAR SCREEN;
SELECT DISTINCT table_name
FROM all_tab_columns
WHERE table_name = TRIM(UPPER('&table_name'));
BEGIN trim_all_columns('table_name');  
SET TERM ON                   
ACCEPT response CHAR PROMPT 'Task completed! Would you like to trim all columns in another table? '
SET TERM OFF

SELECT CASE LOWER('&&response.') WHEN 'yes' THEN 'column_trimmer' ELSE 'no' END AS script
FROM DUAL;

SET TERM ON

@&script

Comment: CLEAR SCREEN
SET VERIFY OFF
ACCEPT table_name CHAR PROMPT 'Please type in table name: '
CLEAR SCREEN;
SELECT DISTINCT table_name
FROM all_tables
BEGIN trim_all_columns('table_name');
  
WHERE table_name = TRIM(UPPER('&table_name'));

ACCEPT response CHAR PROMPT 'Would you like to select another table? '

COLUMN script new_value script

SET TERM OFF

SELECT CASE LOWER('&response.') WHEN 'yes' THEN 'columntrimmer' ELSE 'no' END AS script
FROM DUAL;

SET TERM ON

@&script.

Comment: I changed my mind, I just want to input a table and column and it removes all leading and trailing spaces. This is what I have so far......                                 CLEAR SCREEN SET VERIFY OFF
ACCEPT table_name CHAR PROMPT 'Table Name?: '
ACCEPT column_name CHAR PROMPT 'Column Name?: '
CLEAR SCREEN;
UPDATE ('&table_name') SET ('&column') = TRIM('&column')
ACCEPT response CHAR PROMPT 'Would you like to select another table? '
COLUMN script new_value script
SET TERM OFF
SELECT CASE LOWER('&response.') WHEN 'yes' THEN 'columntrimmer' ELSE 'no' END AS script
FROM DUAL;
SET TERM ON
@&script.

Comment: Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: One more request. I want to put in an option for the user to choose whether or not he/she wants to choose another table to trim spaces. I came up with this code from previous help.......ACCEPT response CHAR PROMPT 'Would you like to search for another column? '
COLUMN script new_value script
SET TERM OFF

SELECT CASE LOWER('&response.') WHEN 'yes' THEN 'columnfinder' ELSE 'stop' END AS script
FROM DUAL;
SET TERM ON
@&script.

Comment: Where would I actually insert these statements? It doesn't have to be exactly like above but after viewing it, you should pretty much get an idea of what I'm trying to do. Thank you ahead of time for all your help!!!